# compare screen shots and get screen coordinates of first pixel change

Tags: delphi

I have two screenshots taken one after another with a few seconds gap. I am comparing both the images and trying to find out if there are any differences between them. If there are any differences, i need to get the screen coordinates of that pixel change.

Can I achieve this using Delphi?

Comment: Having 2 bitmaps with screenshots, use `ScanLine` on both and compare memory of a given row pixel array. If there's a difference, find the pixel, which is different. Do you need to know all the differences or just the first one ?

Comment: ok. got it. finding first change would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have two bitmaps to compare and you need to find a position of the first different pixel, you can iterate the bitmap rows, get the bitmap pixel array for each row of both bitmaps, compare them and if they don't match, find the horizontal position of a different pixel. In code it might look like this:

```
function CompareBitmaps(ABitmap1, ABitmap2: TBitmap;
  var ADiffPixel: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  X, Y: Integer;
  Size: Integer;
  Pixels1, Pixels2: PByteArray;
begin
  // first check if both bitmaps match in size and pixel format
  Result := (ABitmap1.PixelFormat = ABitmap2.PixelFormat) and
    (ABitmap1.Width = ABitmap2.Width) and (ABitmap1.Height = ABitmap2.Height);
  // if so, then...
  if Result then
  begin
    // assign the size of one pixel
    case ABitmap1.PixelFormat of
      pf24bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBTriple);
      pf32bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Bitmap must be 24-bit or 32-bit format!');
    end;
    // iterate all the bitmap rows    
    for Y := 0 to ABitmap1.Height - 1 do
    begin
      // get pointer to pixel data array of the same row for both bitmaps
      Pixels1 := ABitmap1.ScanLine[Y];
      Pixels2 := ABitmap2.ScanLine[Y];
      // compare those pixel data arrays; if they differ, then...
      if not CompareMem(Pixels1, Pixels2, ABitmap1.Width * Size) then
      begin
        // return negative result
        Result := False;
        // assign vertical pixel position to the output ADiffPixel parameter
        ADiffPixel.Y := Y;
        // iterate the current row to find a different pixel; after it's found
        // the pixel's horizontal position is stored to the output ADiffPixel
        // parameter; the pixel array is treated as a byte array, so there's
        // need to be a division by the pixel size
        for X := 0 to ABitmap1.Width * Size - 1 do
          if (Pixels1[X] <> Pixels2[X]) then
          begin
            ADiffPixel.X := X div Size;
            Exit;
          end;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Bitmaps must match in size and pixel format!');
end;
```

And the example usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PixelPos: TPoint;
begin
  if CompareBitmaps(Image1.Picture.Bitmap, Image2.Picture.Bitmap, PixelPos) then
    ShowMessage('Bitmaps are the same!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Bitmaps are different! The first different pixel was found ' +
      'at [' + IntToStr(PixelPos.X) + '; ' + IntToStr(PixelPos.Y) + '].');
end;
```

Comment: wonderful solution. but the pixels I am getting is [23711728,737] .
the y coordinate seems correct. but the x coordinate is not. I will post the correct code if i am able to solve it.

Comment: Do you have that horizontal pixel pos division in the code you've used ? In my code I'm working with an array of bytes, and since one pixel may consist from more than one byte, I'm dividing the found byte position by a count of bytes for one pixel.

Comment: my picture size is 1080X1024.
it seems, if the pixel change is in first half of the picture then it works fine. if the pixel change is in other half i get weird pixel positions

Comment: i have tried out your exact code. 
this line
...
...
       if not CompareMem(Pixels1, Pixels2, ABitmap1.Width * SizeOf(Size)) then
...

gave me access violation exception

Comment: D'oh, sorry. Now I can see that. I should have compare memory in size of a `ABitmap1.Width * Size` not `ABitmap1.Width * SizeOf(Size)`. That `Size` is already a size of a single pixel in bytes and you need to compare memory in size of width * size of a pixel. Fixed...

Comment: this still remains. I am trying to fix this -
"if the pixel change is in first half of the picture then it works fine. if the pixel change is in other half i get weird pixel positions - like [23711728,737]"

Comment: So the last update will be in that horizontal iteration. I should have iterate `for X := 0 to ABitmap1.Width * Size - 1 do` because it's array of bytes, not array of pixels what is iterated. That `x` position you got was the initial value you've passed into the function, because the array was not iterated in its whole length, thus the pixel color channel difference was not found. Now it should work (don't have Delphi by hand to try). Shame on me... :-)

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. shame on me  :(

Comment: You need to break in the inner loop. if (Pixels1[X] <> Pixels2[X]) then begin ADiffPixel.X := X div Size; Break; end;

Comment: @Sertac, thanks! I've finally used `Exit` instead of 2 `Break`s. Dammit, 3 bugs in such simple code...