# Delphi compare 2 similar images

Tags: image, delphi, compare, computer-vision

Is there anyway to compare 2 similar images (not the same) in Delphi.

here are some examples:

[image]&[image]

Its obvious here that we cant compare pixel by pixel, 
So my idea was to sum the pixels values of each image, the compare them:

```
function CalcPix( img : TImage) : longint;
var
  s : longint;
  i, j : integer;
begin
  s := 0;

  for i := 0 to img.Height do
  begin
     for j := 0 to img.Width do
     begin
      if img.Canvas.Pixels[i,j] <> clWhite then
        s := s + img.Canvas.Pixels[i, j];
     end;
  end;

  Result := S;
end;
```

the results are:

1)14836072057

2)16750850318

as you see they are not that close, and if i do this process with 4 - 5 image at a time it always give me wrong results.

Is there anyother way? like changing the color or contrast etc.

Comment: I assume by "compare" you mean to apply some algorithm that will return a degree of correlation between two images?  Such a correlation requires rules about what you consider similar and not similar.  In your example you seem to mean similar in exclusion of a rotation or translation transform.  What about a stretch or a skew, however, or a curvature distortion of some type?  What are you trying to achieve and what form should the result take?  Do you want a *yes/no* match, or a one-dimensional result indicating strength of correlation (ie: 94% probability of match, etc).

Comment: yes, there will be only rotation and translation, and i my goal is to find out, whether the image is the same or not (after it has been rotated/translated)

Comment: Are you looking for similarity or are you looking for identical except for translation/scaling/rotation? There's a whole specific field of research (Image Retrieval) which covers the topic of determining similarity in images.

Comment: no it shouldnt be very identical, it just need to find out if it is the same picture or not ...

Comment: You could compare histograms. Histogram should stay pretty stable and if images are not too similar give good separation.

Comment: @Yassine "if it is the same picture or not" Stop repeating yourself and answer exactly what 'identical' is, i.e the comparison criteria/algorithm. Without that you can't write code. Probably your pixel sum method isn't good enough.

Comment: Here's good write up about the options you have: http://stackoverflow.com/a/844113/7735

Comment: this one will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250619/compare-screen-shots-and-get-screen-coordinates-of-first-pixel-change

Comment: @JanDoggen ok here is what i really wana do, http://bit.ly/146AIAb i have to tell which picture is duplicated there. I hope that was clear enough.

Answer (score 6):

Here's good write up about the options you have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/844113/7735 This requires some background knowledge, and best performing solutions are hard to implement from ground up, so using some kind of library would be easiest. Here's OpenCV wrapper for Delphi: https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

```
function TForm1.ComparaImagens(Imagem1, Imagem2: TImage): boolean;
var
  memImg1, memImg2: TStream;
begin
  memImg1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  memImg2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  
  Imagem1.Bitmap.SaveToStream(memImg1);
  Imagem2.Bitmap.SaveToStream(memImg2);
  
  Result := (memImg1.Size = memImg2.Size);
  
  memImg1.DisposeOf;
  memImg2.DisposeOf;
```

end;

> In my case, compare sizes is sufficient, but if you need read char to char, see [Complete analyse](https://www.devmedia.com.br/comparar-se-imagens-do-tipo-tbitmap-sao-iguais/16085)